# Understanding 編入させていただけますか in this context

Tags: grammar

> 「ーーさしあたって琴里さん、真那も四糸乃さんたちと一緒のタイミングで中学校に編入**させていただけますかね**？さすがにこれから生きていくにあたって、最終学歴小卒ってのはつれーです」

I understand from the context that the speaker, 真那, wanted 琴里 to let 真那 go to the same middle school as 四糸乃etc. I find the first sentence a bit strange. The subject of 編入する is obviously 琴里 but させていただく is used, which sounds like 真那 is going to admit herself to the middle school. Shouldn’t the sentence be 編入していただけますか? Or do I miss something here?

Comment: The sentence roughly means "Kotori, could you please allow me (真那) to go to the middle school?"

Answer (score 2):

That 編入する is intransitive and the subject is 真那.